# Search Pinboard and Google at the same time

Tags: google-search, pinboard

Is there a way to search pinboard when I search google? Evernote has that kind of functionality.

EDIT:
The search functionality I'm looking for is the parallel search functionality that the evernote chrome extension provides. Search Google and it searches pinboard automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how Evernote integrates with Google, but a quick search led me to believe it is done through a Chrome extension.

This might be possible to do with Pinboard as well, it just depends on which Chrome extension fits your needs. Try looking here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/pinboard

Specifically, [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pinboard-search/ipooeblefgjhpfcmpjgccamencpbjodd) will give you Search capability from the Chrome

> Omnibox: Search Pinboard in Omnibox
>
> Pinboard Search provides incremental search for Pinboard. In the
>   Omnibox, type 'p', hit space and then you can search your bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm looking for a parallel search functionality. Updated my post with more details. BTW don't need the extension to search pinboard, you could right click on the pinboard search box, and add it to your list of search engines and give it a keyword 'p'. pretty much the same functionality as the extension if you're logged into pinboard, which I'm pretty much all the time.

Comment: @freethinker I'm confused. Doesn't this answer give you the ability to search both Pinboard and the web-at-large via Google search at the same time? It says "incremental search", and you said "parallel search", but I'm not understanding if that is the issue, and what the distinction between the two are in this context.

Comment: @FeralOink So the intention is to search in google, a normal google search, not to search pinboard, but when I search google, i want a small indicator on top of google search results (like the evernote extension) which indicates that my search phrase/keywords has also yielded some results from the pinboard search. That way if I have already bookmarked a particular tutorial/guide I could refer to that instead of looking thru google results for one that fits my purpose. Does that make it anymore clear?

Comment: @freethinker Yes, it does. I was thinking of a possible solution for you with another search engine, that would combine Google and Pinboard results, I'm not sure if it can do that though. If so, I'll tell you!

Answer (score -2):

How about using IFTTT to copy pins from Pinboard to Evernote and then using the Evernote plugin.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? One-line answers without explanations aren't considered helpful around here.